# Are User Agents always in English?

Tags: browser, user-agent

I am working on making a basic User Agent parser, and was wondering if I would have any I18N issues with an English-centric approach.

For example, in this Safari User Agent...

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1`

would iPhone be translated to iPhonella in Finnish? Also, would non brand name words be translated, such as Mobile and Version.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has this question in the future, I have come to the consensus that the user agent will always be in English. (or at the very least, a specific user agent will always be the same language)

According the the Mozilla documentation, the common user agents are always in English.

[Chinese Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent?)

Additionally, there is a block list on GitHub for Chinese user agents, and the strings it blocks are all in English.

[Chinese UA block rule](https://gist.github.com/0polar/d721715f987247db7194c917de46601e)